# Having local and remote versions of my site in Aptana Studio 3.0, like Dreamweaver does it

Tags: ide, ftp, aptana, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver I could set up a project such that I had the remote side, where my live site would be located, and the local side, where those same exact files resided on my hard drive with the same structure. How can I do this in Aptana Studio 3.0? I only know how to access a site remotely, so I can edit the files just fine, but I can't figure out how to have a permanent home on my hard drive for the files, so I can (for example) upload new files to my server without opening up a separate FTP program.

On their site, Aptana touts the following as one of the [new features of Aptana Studio 2.0](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2/releasenotes):

> Radically improved the remotelocal file transfer features. There is an all-new UI and infrastructure for specifying connections, connecting them with projects, and copying files in each direction.

That sounds like what I want to do, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few wiki pages on creating connections between a local project and a FTP site:

[https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP%2C+SFTP%2C+and+FTPS+Deployment](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/FTP,+SFTP,+and+FTPS+Deployment)

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Create+a+FTP+Connection

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Managing+FTP+Connections

Hope these help.